# Need help styling a div with multiple classes + pseudo classes externally

Tags: html, css

i have a website that i don't have the source code to. I am trying to make changes externally by placing  html's before certain divs to alter how the website looks.

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="absolute zoom-image hidden group-hover:block top-0 border-2 border-[#f3f3f3] overflow-hidden bg-white" style="width: 721px;height: 541px;left: 721px;z-index: 50;"> CONTENT HERE </div>
```

I need to style it making it left:753px , but i can't define the classes of the div like i normally do on other examples.

I am trying this:

```
<style>
.absolute.zoom-image.hidden.group-hover:block.top-0.border-2.border-[#f3f3f3].overflow-hidden.bg-white
{
left:753px !important;
}
</style>
```

Sadly i can't define pseudo classes like this thus it doesnt work, does anyone have any idea how i can do this ?

Clarification:

The problem is i can not modify the div i posted earlier. I must write an additional code to modify it with !important. As i said i do not have the source code so these are not editable to me. I can only add a free html code on somewhere in the page. How can i edit this externally ? I need to write a code that refers this class since the div doesnt have any tags or id's. It has to be a  code that refers to that class. I hope i made my point

Answer (score 0):

Please don't be so confused about how to use the class & style attributes for the CSS. You can use only one class name in order to style your components, also, you don't need to use both inline styles ( here -> style= "width: 721px; height: 541px; left: 721px;z-index: 50;" <- ) and class styling to give CSS to your components.
**Style** attributes are used to write CSS along with the HTML tags. and id or class styling is used to write the CSS commands in a separate space.

This is a separate way to write the styling.

```
<div style="width: 721px; height: 541px; left: 721px; z-index: 50;"> CONTENT HERE </div>
```

Another way can be: -
(Here I used the class name as absolute)

```
<div class="absolute"> CONTENT HERE </div>
<style>
.absolute
{
left:753px;
top:0;
border: 2px solid #f3f3f3;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:white;
zoom:normal; // zoom-image hidden is confusing for me.
}

.absolute:hover{
dispaly:block;
</style>

// I wrote these style commands after decoding whatever you wrote in the class attribute.
```

Do try this code, and also do refer to MDN Docs or any other documentation before write the code.

Comment: Thank you your answer. The problem is i can not modify the div i posted earlier. I must write an additional code to modify it with !important. As i said i do not have the source code so these are not editable to me. I can only add a free html code on somewhere in the page. How can i edit this externally ? I need to write a code that refers this class since the div doesnt have any tags or id's. It has to be a <style></style> code that refers to that class. I hope i made my point